# How to overwrite empty column values in a GROUP BY with SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I need to SUM Col3 but the non-empty value for Col2 needs to be retained. Is there a way to accomplish this with a GROUP BY?

Table

```
Col1           Col2           Col3
-----------------------------------
123           abc              2
123                            3
```

`SELECT` query:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, SUM(Col3)
FROM Table
GROUP BY Col1, Col2
```

Result:

```
Col1          Col2         Col3
--------------------------------
123           abc           5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by only Col1

```
SELECT Col1, Max(Col2) SUM(Col3)
FROM Table
GROUP BY Col1
```

Comment: The non-empty value for Col2 is essential.

Comment: The above solution is kind of "dangerous". What if Col2 for Col1 = 123 has more than one non empty values? Can tis happen in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Add a filter on col2 with a having clause. With this it will remove line 2 that has the null value.

We cannot consider the row that has the null value and use it only for sum(col3).  hence  result would be 123, abc, 2 and not 123, abc, 5

```
select col1, col2, sum(col3) as c from table2
group by col1, col2
having col2 is not null
```

Comment: This won't work because the value for col3 in the row that has an empty value for col2 must be included within the SUM.

Answer (score 0):

For the data you have,

```
select distinct col1, col2, (select sum(col3)) c
from table2
where col2 is not null
```

Comment: Wouldn't this still require col1 to be in an agg or a group by to work?

Comment: It would require no such thing.